# Python Turtle Graphics Game Lagging

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

My Python game is lagging a lot. I started making a new Python game and every time it came to testing it, it would always lag although I am not using any images.

```
import turtle
import random

#head orientation
h = [0]

#score
a = [0]
b = [0]

#food coord
fcoord = [0,0,0]

#position
pos = []


def home(x,y):
    x = 0
    y = 0
    a[0] = 0
    b[0] = 0
    h[0] = 0
    fcoord[2] = 0
    pos[:] = []
    turtle.hideturtle()
    turtle.clear()
    turtle.pu()
    turtle.color("lime")
    turtle.goto(0,0)
    turtle.write("PLAY", align="center",font="Calibri")
    turtle.title("Snake Game")
    turtle.onscreenclick(start)
    turtle.mainloop()

def level_1():
    turtle.clear()
    turtle.pu()
    turtle.speed(0)
    turtle.pensize(20)
    turtle.color("grey")
    turtle.goto(-220,220)
    turtle.pd()
    turtle.goto(220,220)
    turtle.goto(220,-220)
    turtle.goto(-220,-220)
    turtle.goto(-220,220)
    turtle.pu()
    turtle.goto(0,0)

def start(x,y):
    turtle.onscreenclick(None)

    level_1()

    tfood = turtle.Turtle()
    tfood.hideturtle()
    tfood.pu()
    tfood.speed(0)
    tfood.shape("square")
    tfood.color("red")

    tscore = turtle.Turtle()
    tscore.hideturtle()
    tscore.pu()
    tscore.speed(0)
    tscore.goto(100,-250)
    tscore.write("Score:" + str(a[0]), align="center",font=(10))

    while x > -210 and x < 210 and y > -210 and y <210:
        if fcoord[2] == 0:
            food(tfood)
            fcoord[2] = 1
        turtle.onkey(u,"Up")
        turtle.onkey(l,"Left")
        turtle.onkey(r,"Right")
        turtle.onkey(d,"Down")
        turtle.listen()
        move()
        x = turtle.xcor()
        y = turtle.ycor()        
        if x > fcoord[0]*20-5 and x < fcoord[0]*20+5 and y > fcoord[1]*20-5 and y < fcoord[1]*20+5:
            fcoord[2] = 0
            tfood.clear()
            a[0] += 1
            tscore.clear()
            tscore.write("Score:" + str(a[0]), align="center",font=(10))

        if len(pos) > 1:
            for i in range(1,len(pos)):
                if x < pos[i][0]+5 and x > pos[i][0]-5 and y < pos[i][1]+5 and y > pos[i][1]-5:
                        tscore.clear()
                        tfood.clear()
                        gameover()
    tscore.clear()
    tfood.clear()
    gameover()


#Food
def food(tfood):
    x = random.randrange(-8,8,1)
    y = random.randrange(-8,8,1)
    fcoord[0] = x
    fcoord[1] = y
    tfood.hideturtle()
    tfood.pu()
    tfood.shape("circle")
    tfood.color("red")
    tfood.goto(x*20,y*20)
    tfood.stamp()

#Up   
def u():
    if h[0] == 270:
        pass
    else:
        h[0] = 90
#Down
def d():
    if h[0] == 90:
        pass
    else:
        h[0] = 270
#Left
def l():
    if h[0] == 0:
        pass
    else:
        h[0] = 180
#Right
def r():
    if h[0] == 180:
        pass
    else:
        h[0] = 0

def move():
    turtle.pensize(1)
    turtle.color("green")
    turtle.pu()
    turtle.speed(3)
    turtle.setheading(h[0])
    turtle.shape("square")
    turtle.stamp()
    turtle.fd(20)
    x = turtle.xcor()
    y = turtle.ycor()
    if b[0] > a[0]:     
        turtle.clearstamps(1)
        pos.insert(0,[round(x),round(y)])
        pos.pop(-1)
    else:
        pos.insert(0,[round(x),round(y)])       
        b[0] += 1    

def gameover():
    turtle.onscreenclick(None)
    turtle.speed(0)
    turtle.pu()
    turtle.goto(0,150)
    turtle.color("red")
    turtle.write("Game Over",align="center", font=(10))
    turtle.goto(0,50)
    turtle.write("Score:" + str(a[0]),align="center",font=(10))
    turtle.goto(200,-200)
    turtle.write("(Click anywhere to return to the main menu)",align="right",font=(0.0000001))
    turtle.onscreenclick(home)
    turtle.mainloop()


# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
# Main                                    #
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
if __name__ == '__main__':
    home(0,0)
```

Comment: From what I can tell, you have a while loop without any sort of frames per second management so its going to be going through the while loop a lot more than it needs to

Comment: Your question should *only* contain your question. I removed the gratuitous and spammy link to your site. See also [How not to be a spammer](/help/promotion)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by *lagging* but I've addressed a couple of issues in my rewrite below.  The first is that turtles are global entities that don't get garbage collected under normal circumstances so don't *recreate* them, *reuse* them instead.  Second, when you have your own `while` loop to control the game, you potentially lock out events.  I've eliminated your loop and modified the game to work with `ontimer` events so that turtle movement should be handled by the same event loop that's handing user input, making it slightly more responsive to the user:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
from random import randint

FONT = ('Arial', 18, 'bold')

# Up
def u():
    if h[0] != 270:
        h[0] = 90
# Down
def d():
    if h[0] != 90:
        h[0] = 270
# Left
def l():
    if h[0] != 0:
         h[0] = 180
# Right
def r():
    if h[0] != 180:
            h[0] = 0

def gameover():

    screen.onkey(None, "Up")
    screen.onkey(None, "Left")
    screen.onkey(None, "Right")
    screen.onkey(None, "Down")

    tscore.clear()
    tfood.clear()
    tplayer.clear()

    tfood.hideturtle()
    tplayer.hideturtle()

    tscore.color("red")

    tscore.goto(0, 150)
    tscore.write("Game Over", align="center", font=FONT)

    tscore.goto(0, 50)
    tscore.write("Score:" + str(a[0]), align="center", font=FONT)

    tscore.goto(0, -200)
    tscore.write("(Click anywhere to return to the main menu)", align="center", font=FONT)

    screen.onscreenclick(home)

def food(tfood):

    x = randint(-160, 160)
    y = randint(-160, 160)

    tfood.goto(x, y)
    tfood.showturtle()

def move():
    x, y = tplayer.position()

    if -210 < x < 210 and -210 < y < 210:
        if not tfood.isvisible():
            food(tfood)

        tplayer.setheading(h[0])
        tplayer.stamp()
        tplayer.forward(20)


        if b[0] > a[0]:
            tplayer.clearstamps(1)
            pos.insert(0, [round(x), round(y)])
            pos.pop(-1)
        else:
            pos.insert(0, [round(x), round(y)])
            b[0] += 1

        if tplayer.distance(tfood) < 15:
            tfood.hideturtle()
            tfood.clear()
            a[0] += 1
            tscore.clear()
            tscore.write("Score:" + str(a[0]), align="center", font=FONT)

        flag = True
        x, y = tplayer.position()

        if len(pos) > 1:
            for i in range(1, len(pos)):
                if pos[i][0] - 5 < x < pos[i][0] + 5 and pos[i][1] - 5 < y < pos[i][1] + 5:
                    flag = False
                    break

        if flag:
            screen.ontimer(move, 25)
    else:
        screen.ontimer(gameover, 100)

def level_1():

    tmarker.penup()
    tmarker.goto(-220, 220)
    tmarker.pendown()
    tmarker.goto(220, 220)
    tmarker.goto(220, -220)
    tmarker.goto(-220, -220)
    tmarker.goto(-220, 220)
    tmarker.penup()

def start(x, y):
    screen.onscreenclick(None)

    tscore.clear()

    level_1()

    tplayer.home()
    tplayer.setheading(h[0])

    tscore.goto(100, -250)
    tscore.write("Score:" + str(a[0]), align="center", font=FONT)

    screen.onkey(u, "Up")
    screen.onkey(l, "Left")
    screen.onkey(r, "Right")
    screen.onkey(d, "Down")

    move()

def home(x=0, y=0):
    screen.onscreenclick(None)

    a[0] = 0
    b[0] = 0
    h[0] = 0

    pos[:] = []

    tscore.clear()
    tscore.home()
    tscore.color('lime')
    tscore.write("PLAY", align="center", font=FONT)

    screen.onscreenclick(start)

# head orientation
h = [0]

# score
a = [0]
b = [0]

# position
pos = []

# turtles
tfood = Turtle('circle', visible=False)
tfood.speed('fastest')
tfood.color('red')
tfood.penup()

tscore = Turtle(visible=False)
tscore.speed('fastest')
tscore.penup()

tplayer = Turtle("square", visible=False)
tplayer.speed('slow')
tplayer.color("green")
tplayer.penup()

tmarker = Turtle(visible=False)
tmarker.speed('fastest')
tmarker.pensize(20)
tmarker.color("grey")

# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
# Main                                    #
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
if __name__ == '__main__':
    screen = Screen()
    screen.title("Snake Game")
    screen.listen()

    home()

    screen.mainloop()
```